# How would you create a generic Factory type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to create a generic typescript type for factories.

I started with this class:

```
class Car {
    private brand: string;

    constructor(brand: string) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    printBrand() {
        console.log(this.brand);
    }
}
```

and created the following type:

```
type CarFactory = (...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Car>) => Car;
```

so then i could create the factory function:

```
const createCar: CarFactory = (brand: string) => {
    return new Car(brand);
};
```

Here is my question: is it possible to define a generic type like:

```
type Factory<T> = (...args: any[]) => T;
```

without using `any[]` and having a constraint on the constructor parameters for T?

Comment: Yes, your edit is correct. You could post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to @Tobias S. i edited my question to post the solution i found:

```
type Factory<T extends new (... args: any[]) => any> = (... args: ConstructorParameters<T>) => InstanceType<T>;

type CarFactory = Factory<typeof Car>;

const createCar: CarFactory = (brand: string) => {
    return new Car(brand);
};

createCar('Peugeot').printBrand();
```